# Why can I see div inserted by fbevents

Tags: javascript, facebook, web, html

I can see a div inserted by fbevent.js when I browse webpages.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be bug and is being resolved by Facebook ads team.

See https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/336662116810282/ for the progress.